# Using Dictionary with list manipulation

Tags: python

How do you use dictionary to find the index in the elements of the list however it should return the index of the same element.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and explain what difficulties you are facing in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
    text = "I like cheese bcoz cheese in great"
    hash = {}
    words = text.split(" ")
    for i in range(1:len(words)):
       word = words[i] 
       if word not in hash.keys():
             hash[word] = i

    for word in words:
       print hash[word]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = "I like cheese because cheese is great".split()
d = {}
count = 0
for word in l:
    if word not in d.keys():
        count += 1
        d[i] = count
for word in l:
    print(d[word], end=",")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

```
text = "I like cheese because cheese is great"
d = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(text.split(), 1)}
print(d)
```